# Youtube API (v3) and CORS preflight

Tags: angularjs, youtube-api, cors

---

### EDIT: Looks like this post is much ado about nothing, as the OPTIONS preflighting was introduced late last fall; my problems have been more user error than anything. See comments for more details (I'll leave it all here for documentation's sake). --jlm

---

It's a known issue that the Youtube API does not support the OPTIONS request method, so any web app that tries to do a Cross-Origin preflight will fail, even if (as is the case with the Youtube API) the actual CORS request would succeed. As we've been facing this issue yet again this week, we've come up with three workarounds; however, each has it's own plusses and minuses.

**POSSIBLE WORKAROUND #1: Forget the preflight, and just make the simple cross-origin request.**

*Benefits* -- A) it works. B) this is all the specification requires when doing most GET or POST requests.

*Drawbacks* -- A) The specification states that any PATCH, PUT, or DELETE requests, along with POST requests that use a content-type other than form-data, url-encoded, or text/plain,  need to be preflighted. So while it would work, it would be breaking the spec (which we'd like to avoid if possible). B) Preflighting is also necessary when setting custom headers; so, for example, when I use AngularJS's $http method in the 1.0 branch, it sets a custom header and thus triggers preflighting of even GET requests. In this case, of course, I could write my own $http service or move to the 1.1 branch (as the problem would really be on Angluar's end).

**POSSIBLE WORKAROUND #2: Use JSON-P**

*Benefits* -- A) it works, too (in some cases, anyway). B) It's fairly simple to set up.

*Drawbacks* -- A) An older technology, and it isn't clear if the Youtube API will continue to support JSONP. B) Requires a callback. C) Is limited to GET requests only.

**POSSIBLE WORKAROUND #3: Set up a server-side proxy on the same domain, use it to communicate with the Youtube API.**

*Benefits* -- A) Avoids the need to do CORS requests at all, since the client works on the same origin and the server-side proxy has no need to preflight anything.

*Drawbacks* -- A) Can get complicated to set up, especially if trying to work with credentials (oAuth2 through a proxy can be quite the beast).

So that this post has an actual question (or several, actually)

1. What take do you have (for better for worse) on any or all of the workarounds above?
2. Has anyone implemented other solutions?
3. Is there any information as to if/when the Youtube servers might support the OPTIONS method?

Any and all comments are welcome -- and I apologize in advance if this isn't the best forum for such a question (although I'm hoping that by putting it here on Stack Overflow, it'll prove useful to others facing the same issue)

Comment: Just a question about the Youtube API - does it support any "non simple" CORS requests (requests that require preflight)? Because I can't understand how they can do that without supporting preflight. And if they don't support it I can't see why you would need to "break the specs" on the client side (nor do I understand *how* you could do it)?

Comment: The gdata.youtube.com and www.googleapis.com servers do support OPTIONS preflight requests, and CORS is expected to work. The one exception is for uploads.gdata.youtube.com, as I've never been able to successfully complete a v2 CORS upload, and that's something that the engineering team is working on. Do you have an example of YouTube API calls that fail the OPTIONS preflight?

Comment: I think I'm going to backtrack some here after investigating further, as I discovered in the client I was using a problem with the "Access-Control-Request-Method" header. Fixing that fixes some requests (And I'm glad to see OPTIONS working -- I hadn't checked in since a thread from last August led me to believe it still wasn't supported!) However, I am still seeing that the OPTIONS preflight fails when Access-Control-Request-Headers is set to 'X-Requested-With' -- is this expected behavior (I'm assuming it is)?

Comment: @JeffPosnick does the engineering team still work on CORS ( uploads.gdata.youtube.com ) ? I think it's almost an year since they started . There are few open issues on google code ( see http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4050 )

Answer (score 0):

Youtube upload API(uploads.gdata.youtube.com)  doesn't support CORS.

You may vote the issues [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4050) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3699) . There are also several forum posts about it. [CORS is not working !](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/H1vbpy_lwf0)

It seems Google is still working to fix it , though started working on it about an year ago so most likely the API will be deprecated before to have the issue fixed(as we already have a V3).

The only workaround is to use a proxy(which is not cool). Basically upload the video on your server and then send it to youtube.