# Fail to upload a video from front-end with youtube data API v3 due to CORS

Tags: cors, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a JS video editor which runs on the front end. As a result, I get a video stream which I want to consume uploading to the user's youtube channel as the video processses and I get the chunks in the stream. I went through the documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol (which is a bit outtaded) and, after some research, found the following solution, which work flawlessly with postman:

1st step: Authorize the user and get an access token.

2nd step: make a POST request to the API with the acces token on the "Authorization" header and obtain the upload URl, which will be recieved in the response header "Location".

Below a print with postman request and response for ilustration. In the response header there is an entry with "Location" key and a URl as value.

[image: POST request to set video metadata and recieve]

3rd step: Make a PUT request to the URl obtained on step 2 with the video blob/stream in the request body.

Problem is, either in step 2 or 3, when I try to fecth https://www.googleapis.com/... I get blocked by CORS... Since the first request is a POST request, I worked around adding mode:"no-cors" to the fetch options. However the second request, in which the video is acctualy sent, is a PUT request and fetch doesn't allow option no-cors for it, which put me on a dead-end... In postman work as charm and the video is uploaded... I also confirmed I can fecth other resources from within the same script I am trying to fetch the youtube API, which demostrates the CORS issue is on the API side...

I did an extensive research and the best answer to this problem I found was this: [Youtube API (v3) and CORS preflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744529/youtube-api-v3-and-cors-preflight), despite it is an old thread, the conclusion is that the API should support CORS.

The code I run on the script and that returns the fail to fetch error is below, already with the URl obtained from the 1st request:

let options = {
method:'PUT',
body:readbale,
duplex:'half'}

```
  fetch([url obtained from POST request],options);
```

And the error I get shows up as following:

[image]

Comment: The only solution in this case is to set up and use your own server-side proxy — either a specialized off-the-self CORS proxy, or else just roll your own proxy for your specific needs. There is otherwise no way to solve it just from frontend code, from the client side. Instead, you must introduce and maintain some server-side piece. Browsers will otherwise block whatever attempts you might make a trying to solve it only from frontend client-side code (because that’s what the standards require browsers to do, and that’s the way web security works).

Comment: Well, I really taught it was a dead end, thanks for confirming that, so I'll stop attempting to find a solution. I can set a route on my server and then send the stream there, and then to YT. However, beyond the extra work to setup the streams, I am also afraid that this will saturate my server (heroku poor man's server) very easyly... So, for now, I'll let the users save the video to disk and upload to YT them selfs.